# import oracle 11g database dump file into 18c XE , success import but can't find the data or the users

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, database-administration

I'm trying to import oracle 11g DB dump file into my new 18c XE by following these instructions:
To import data in your 18c XE database, perform the following steps:

1. Connect to the 18c XE database as user SYS using the SYSDBA privilege.
2. Create directory object DUMP_DIR and grant READ and WRITE privileges on the directory to the SYSTEM user.

```
sqlplus / AS SYSDBA
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=XEPDB1;
SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY DUMP_DIR AS '\dump_folder';
SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DUMP_DIR TO SYSTEM;
```

3. Import data to the 18c XE database from the dump folder.

```
impdp system/system_password@localhost:listnerport/xepdb1 full=Y EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:\"LIKE \'APEX_%\'\",SCHEMA:\"LIKE \'FLOWS_%\'\" directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=DB11G.dmp logfile=impdpDB11G.log
```

and I'm getting the following response witch looks like success:

[image: command execution]

but when I connect to xepdb1, I find that REPORTS schema and users are not imported, non of the data are loaded

am I missing something?

update 1: The full text log

```
;;; 
Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Jun 23 11:26:23 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  system/********@localhost:1521/xepdb1 full=Y EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:"LIKE \'APEX_%\'",SCHEMA:"LIKE \'FLOWS_%\'" directory=DUMP1_DIR dumpfile=DATABASE2.dmp logfile=DATABASE2.log 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TYPE/TYPE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "REPORTS"."TV_REPORTS"                      14.14 KB      13 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO"               25.38 KB      10 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_DATA_SOURCES"             11.34 KB       2 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."Y_AUDIT"                         17.78 KB      78 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."A7BAR1"                          9.648 KB     184 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."A7BAR_TEST"                      8.656 KB      86 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."CENTER"                            5.5 KB       5 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."CONSTRAINT_LOOKUP"               5.515 KB       1 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_CONSTRAINT_LOOKUP"          5.679 KB       4 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_CUSTOMERS"                  11.01 KB       7 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_ORDERS"                     7.367 KB      10 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS"                7.734 KB      49 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_STATES"                     6.242 KB      51 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_TAGS"                        8.25 KB       6 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_TAGS_SUM"                   5.476 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEMO_TAGS_TYPE_SUM"              5.906 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DEPT"                            5.937 KB       4 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."DISTENY_REPORT"                  5.414 KB       1 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_ACCESS_LEVELS"            5.468 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_CATEGORIES"               8.359 KB       1 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_DATASRC_TYPES"            8.492 KB       2 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_DEMO_PROJECTS"            17.32 KB      73 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_DEMO_TABLE"               14.75 KB     121 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_ERROR_LOOKUP"             5.882 KB       1 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_FORMAT_MASKS"             6.875 KB      25 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_PREFERENCES"              8.101 KB      10 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_RESERVED_NAMES"           7.562 KB       1 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_RPT_TYPES"                10.28 KB       5 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_TAGS"                     8.382 KB       8 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_TAGS_SUM"                   5.5 KB       6 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_TAGS_TYPE_SUM"            5.968 KB       6 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_USERS"                    8.328 KB       1 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_WHITELIST_OBJECTS"        8.484 KB       2 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_WIDGET_TYPES"             15.90 KB       4 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EMP"                             8.570 KB      14 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EMPLOYEE"                        7.914 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."GUEST"                           6.765 KB       5 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."JOB_TITLE"                       5.476 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."REPORTEMPLOYEELINK"              5.859 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."REPORTEVAL"                      5.976 KB       6 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."REPORT_GUESTLINK"                5.453 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."REPORT_SHOW"                     5.851 KB       2 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."REPORT_TAPELINK"                 5.875 KB       4 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."REPORT_TYPE"                     5.421 KB       1 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."R_ORGANIZATION"                  6.367 KB       4 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."TAPETYPE"                        5.421 KB       2 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."TAPE_INFO"                       5.843 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."TVPROGRAM"                       5.882 KB       3 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."USERS_YARA"                      6.257 KB       2 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_ACL"                           0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_WS_FILES"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_WS_HISTORY"                    0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_WS_LINKS"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_WS_NOTES"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_WS_ROWS"                       0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_WS_TAGS"                       0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_WS_WEBPG_SECTIONS"             0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."APEX$_WS_WEBPG_SECTION_HISTORY"      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_CALENDARS"                    0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_DATA_SOURCE_PERMS"            0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_ERRORS"                       0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_FAVORITES"                    0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_FILES"                        0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_FILTER_REPORT"                0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_FILTER_RPT_FILTERS"           0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_HISTORY"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_INVOCATIONS"                  0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_NOTES"                        0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_NOTIFICATIONS"                0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_PDF_RPT"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_PDF_RPT_SRC"                  0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_PDF_RPT_SRC_COLS"             0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_REPORTS"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_REPORT_PERMS"                 0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_REPORT_VALIDATIONS"           0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_RPT_VAL_DEPENDENCYS"          0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_USER_PREF"                    0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_VIEWERS"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_VIEWER_GROUPS"                0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_VIEWER_GROUP_REF"             0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."EBA_DP_WIDGETS"                      0 KB       0 rows
. . imported "REPORTS"."REPORT_ORGALINK"                     0 KB       0 rows
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/COMPILE_PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC/ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_BODY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_AND_BITMAP/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_AND_BITMAP/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/POST_SCHEMA/PROCOBJ
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at Tue Jun 23 11:27:00 2020 elapsed 0 00:00:29
```

Comment: Please post the whole import log file (in text mode): we need it to check for any warning or error.

Comment: From SYS, query in `DBA_USERS` to check if `REPORTS` schema is created or not

Comment: @pifor I posted the full log,

Comment: @Tejash I checked and the user is not there

Comment: This should work. Double check that you are connected to the right PDB  ie `XEPDB1` (with sqlplus: `show con_name`) when checking for user in DBA_USERS and for data in application schemas. Are you really sure that export is export FULL ? (I made a similar test from 11.2.0.4 to 19.5 - with `FULL` you should get many expected warnings about Oracle owned schemas).

Comment: @pifor yeah this was the issue, my colleague was not connected to the right DB, all the data are imported successfully , it got me confused really, sorry for the trouble , I'll delete the question as it might be misleading

Comment: You don't need to delete the question: working with PDB is something new for many Oracle users and it's easy to get confused (especially if you have been working a lot with older Oracle releases where this feature did not exist).

Comment: OK I'll keep it, thanks for the support @pifo

Comment: Where did you get "the following steps"?  Especially "Connect to the 18c XE database as user SYS using the SYSDBA privilege."  The documentation (Database Utilities), under "3.2 Invoking Data Pump Import"  _very specifically_ says "Note:

Do not start Import as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users.

Comment: @EdStevens I got this from oracle documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/exporting-and-importing-data-oracle-database-xe-11.2-and-18c.html#GUID-F496A4B2-0C3E-430C-B4A8-3C1F13289738

Comment: My mistake, that's what I get for speed reading.  Since my mind was already primed for impdp issues, I jumped when I saw 'as sysdb', without paying attention to the fact that it was for issuing some sql, not for invoking impdp. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check imported data in a pluggable database, you need to be connected to the target pluggable database with:

```
alter session set container=<pdb>;
```